# Electric field in conductor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, conductors

consider there  is 3 electron in surface of a sphere they will be arrange themselves in a triangle  shape (because they want to be as much distance  from each other).

now put an electron in center of this sphere, it can not change the arrangement of system  so the place of electron in surface still unchanged but there is no electric field in sphere too, so this new electron will stand still in center too.

but it is against the gauss law that say charged will go to surface, how explain it

improving  :I means if we place an electron in somewhere of a solid conductor sphere , I place it somehow that the arrangement of electron in the surface will not change , before I place electron there is no field in sphere , after that also ( because arrangement did not change) there would be no field , with no field there would be no force in this new electron so it will remain in its position , but its against gauss law ( the charge always stay in surface) ? how it can be explained?

please give positive contributions so I get out of a question ban

Comment: There is no electric field inside an *empty* sphere. With an electron in the middle, it is no longer empty.

Comment: I  say  in this situation the center electron will not go to surface (because there is no force)and it is against  law that charge in conductor will be always in  surface

Comment: Is the spherical conductor a solid sphere or a hollow shell? In other words, is the central charge in the conductor or not? Also, is the sphere conductive? I assumed so but you are not clear

Answer (score 2):

The three electrons on the surface of a solid conducting sphere would define a plane.  For maximum separation, that plane must pass through the center of the sphere.  A fourth electron placed at the center would be in a position of unstable equilibrium.  At any temperature above absolute zero it would be in thermal equilibrium with surrounding atoms.  Its thermal motion would carry it away from equilibrium, and the force from the other three electrons would push it to the surface.